# Integrated Intel GPU is faster than Radeon one on MacBook

Tags: swift, macos, gpu, metal, core-image

I'm writing an app that extensively uses CoreImage filters + custom shaders. Usual case is:

1. Load and cache large RAW file from hard drive through `CIFilter(imageURL)`
2. Apply corrections (tint, temp, exposure)
3. Apply random CoreImage pre-defined filters
4. Apply custom-written shaders
5. Render everything to `MTLTexture`
6. Render from MTLTexture to screen
7. Go to step 2.

Now, we observed on various MacBooks (e.g. late 2014) that this code runs faster if target MTLDevice is Intel integrated GPU, rather than high performance Radeon attached to MBP.

Any ideas why is that? I would expect Radeon to be way faster.

edit:

---

Tested cards:

- "Radeon Pro 460 4096 MB" vs "Intel HD Graphics 530 1536MB"
- "NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2GB GDDR5" vs "Intel Iris Pro Graphics"

Simplified version of code we're using:

```
let filter = CIFilter(imageURL: urlToRawFile20MBLarge)

class Renderer: MTKView {
    override func draw() {

        filter.setValue(temp, forKey: kCIInputNeutralTemperatureKey)

        let image: CIImage = filter.cropped(to: rect)
                                   // uses CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur").outputImage
                                   .applyBlurFilter(radius: radius)
                                   .applyCustomShader1(param: x)
                                   .applyCustomShader2(param: y)

        // ... create command buffer and `CIRenderDestination`

        do {
            try ciContext.startTask(toClear: dest)
            try ciContext.startTask(toRender: image, to: dest)
        } catch {
            log(error)
        }

        if let drawable = currentDrawable {
            commandBuffer.present(drawable)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Saying "Radeon graphics card" doesn't say much more than "a Ford car". Is it a Mustang, or a Fiesta?

Comment: Probably the integrated GPU can directly access the main memory, while the dedicated GPU has its own memory so you end up copying the image back and forth in that case, which dominates the gains in processing power.

Comment: You would have to show us actual code. **How** are you applying those things? **How** are you rendering to the texture and from the texture to the screen? Those details will inform about how many times the image data needs to be transferred back and forth between the CPU and GPU.

Comment: @TamásZahola thanks, that makes sense. Is there a way to verify/measure what you're saying, e.g. with instruments?

Comment: @KenThomases I added simplified version of code we're using

Comment: @Alexander I added tested graphic cards above.